navbar problem changing size on zoom html css
I need help, I currently have a problem that I encounter on my site when I zoom out/zoom in on my site, when I do this, the size and position of the elements of the navbar changes. I would like this to remain fixed as on the first screen and for the elements not to change position or increase or decrease.
Like here for example, when you zoom out/zoom in, the size and position does not change on this site (https://getbootstrap.com/):
https://i.imgur.com/uUpkgmV.png
But on my site, when I zoom in/out it does this:
https://i.imgur.com/qqJJpO0.png
And I want it to stay like this even when we zoom out/zoom in:
https://i.imgur.com/59yAgDY.png
Could help me, I think a css function would solve the problem. I can provide the code for the navbar if you wish as well ?
I try to add max-width: 1580px !important; but not working.

can you share the code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm a bit of a newbie myself, but I'm just adding in some input (for an assignment).
It could be simply because of the browser's behaviour.
You can try implementing a responsive view on your CSS sheet. This would mean that it could accommodate to different sizes.
I found this on w3 schools that may help with finding the dimensions.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
Another way that I could think of is if you keep the nav bar in a container, and fix the settings in CSS, as referenced from royalstsp here.
How to keep a <div> constant in size as the user zooms in and out on the page?
.box {
    background: red;
    width: 5vw;
    height: 10vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    left: 5vw;
}

<div class="box"></div>

vh and vw would be the view height and width!
